# How to build window electron executable program with babel

Tags: electron, electron-builder

Actually I can build to use `electron --trace-warnings -r @babel/register .` and with `@babel`

`electron-builder --windows nsis:ia32` command is success as a result
but i execute that, it occur error.

```js
A JavaScript eror occured in the main process

C:\dev\electron\SomeDirectoryPath123123\index.js:1
import {app, BrowserWindow} from "electron";
^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement  outside a module
    at Object.compileFuntion (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
...etc...
```

[image]
please help me..

### .babelrc

```json
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "test app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "helpp me",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "manual-run": "electron --trace-warnings -r @babel/register .",
    "build-package": "electron-builder --windows nsis:ia32"
  },
  "author": "nother",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.5",
    "@babel/node": "^7.18.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/register": "^7.17.7",
    "electron": "^19.0.4",
    "electron-builder": "^23.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.5",
    "@babel/node": "^7.18.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/register": "^7.17.7",
    "elasticsearch": "^16.7.3",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "mongodb": "^4.7.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.7",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.8"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "test-electron-app",
    "productName": "hello!",
    "buildDependenciesFromSource": false,
    "asar": true,
    "files": [
      "dist/**/*",
      "package.json",
      "index.js"
    ],
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false
    },
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "./build/",
      "output": "./distout/"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: try using require instead... `const {app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron")`

Comment: @alexpdev That way is have to change all the files, so Im looking for an easier way